# Compare duplicates for 4 fields in open SQL

Tags: combinations, abap, factorial, opensql

I want to compare if there are duplicates across 4 fields in open SQL.

Scenario: User has 4 fields to input. First name (N1), last name (N2), additional first name (N3) and additional last name (N4).

Right now the algorithm works this way: It concatenates N1 + N2 + % and then also
N2+ N1 + %. So if the user inputs in any of the fields, the query looks for N1N2% or N2N1%. This mean for 2 fields, there are 2! combinations possible. Now with 2 additional fields, this algorithm explodes as there will be 4! combinations to check. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Note: We do this kind of combination check because the user could input data in any of those given input field. So we check for all combination of fields. Unfortunately, this cannot be changed.

EDIT:
I cannot assume the order as it was previously designed in such a way. Hence, the complications with combinations.

Edit2:
I like the idea of checking individual parts. But what we want to do is ideally concatenate all strings together and check for a substring in DB. In open-sql its done using the like statement. Our DB table has such concatenated string already stored for N1+N2 combination. This needs to be extended for 4 fields now.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you trying to find a user in the database based upon the user details entered in some form? Can't you assume even the correct order of the fields?

Comment: Why does it have to be done with an OpenSQL query and why can't you use regular expressions for that purpose?

Comment: Try %N1% AND %N2% AND %N3% AND %N4% AND (N1% OR N2% OR N3% OR N4%) and check that the total size is exactly the sum of all parts

Comment: I added additional comment for order

Comment: Do you really want the db entry the start with an arbitrary order of the name parts followed by potentially any other text?

Comment: Would the following condition be an option? `N1 IN ('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4') AND N2 IN ('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4') AND N3 IN ('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4') AND N4 IN ('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4')`?

Comment: The % indicates, that there is only one field in the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problem is checking all name parts individually with leading and trailing '%' and check the total size of the db entry against the sum of the name parts:

field = ('%' + N1 + '%') AND field = ('%' + N2 + '%') AND field = ('%' + N3 + '%') AND field = ('%' + N4 + '%') AND LENGTH(field) = LENGTH(N1+N2+N3+N4)

This will find a match. You could use it to SELECT a normalized concatenation of the names and use GROUP BY and HAVING count(*)>1 to search for duplicates.

Comment: Check the edit2. I like the idea of comparing individual fields. But the how is length helping here? Like in open-sql looks for a substring. So essentially it is already acting like a pattern matcher.

Comment: The total length ensures, there are no other characters hidden, so if string "foo" is contained anywhere in string x and string "bar" is contained anywhere in string x, then the string might look like "moobarmoofoo". If you ensure length(x)=length(foo)+length(bar), then string x must be "foobar" or "barfoo".

Comment: thanks..I think it solves my problem of getting all possible combinations. I will mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not care about the order and you want to check for duplicates then the following condition seems to meet your criteria I think.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
  INTO TABLE ...
  WHERE N1 IN (@INPUT_N1, @INPUT_N2, @INPUT_N3, @INPUT_N4)
    AND N2 IN (@INPUT_N1, @INPUT_N2, @INPUT_N3, @INPUT_N4)
    AND N3 IN (@INPUT_N1, @INPUT_N2, @INPUT_N3, @INPUT_N4)
    AND N4 IN (@INPUT_N1, @INPUT_N2, @INPUT_N3, @INPUT_N4).

IF sy-dbcnt > 0.
   "duplicates found, do something...
ENDIF.
```

Of course when there is garbage in the database where for example all the four fields are the same, then this will not return a real duplicate.